# jquery ready event not working in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript and I have no idea why this code is not working in my html document. I am trying to get an alert after my document is ready. I've checked and it seems syntactically correct to me. the script is at the top of my html document. Any help is appreciated!

It works if it is invoked directly like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
       alert("My First Jquery Test");
   });
</script>
```

but doesn't work when trying to invoke after document is ready:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function test1(){
    alert("My First Jquery Test");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    test1();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try reversing the order of ) and } on the last line in your example code. It should be });

Comment: I did that and it still does not work. Have no idea why.

Comment: Then I'm guessing your problem is jQuery isn't being loaded. Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` as the first line, then try.

Comment: do you see any errors in the console ?

Comment: Awesome, you were correct userbd. By the way, what is the difference between versions 2.x and 1.x of the jquery libraries?

Comment: "jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8." -- http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: I see thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, I don't think i can approve your comment as the correct answer.

Comment: @userbd That might be an over simplification.... quanuw there are are decent number of changes to the API from 1.x to the newest 2.x . If you're just starting out, you should use the newest version available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make sure that jQuery is loaded. Otherwise,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    test1();
});
```

will not work. If you add

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌
```

as the first line of your code, jQuery will load from Google's hosted library and your code should work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Bracket / parentheses problem:

Last line should read `});`

If you pop open your dev tools (F12 most browsers) you will probably see a parse error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    test1();
)};
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    test1();
});
```

Comment: I made the edit and it still does not work. No alert is showing up.